# Submatrix assignment

Tags: matlab

I have a question regarding computation time of the assignment of a submatrix.
I used to have a code like that:

```
B_tot(1:6,pos:pos+2) = [ddx 0 0;0 ddy 0;0 0 ddz;ddy ddx 0;0 ddz ddy;ddz 0 ddx];
```

According to the Matlab profiler, this line takes 3.91s (it is executed more than 800,000 times). I had the feeling it takes way to long, so I replaced it by:

```
B_tot(1,pos) = ddx;
B_tot(2,pos+1) = ddy;
B_tot(3,pos+2) = ddz;
B_tot(4,pos) = ddy;
B_tot(4,pos+1) = ddx;
B_tot(5,pos+1) = ddz;
B_tot(5,pos+2) = ddy;
B_tot(6,pos) = ddz;
B_tot(6,pos+2) = ddx;
```

The computation time is combined only 0.22s, thus a lot faster.

My question is now: Why is the submatrix assignment so much slower and can I write such an assignment in a good looking way which is still not as time consuming?

Edit:
I made a reproducable code for comparison:

```
tic
for i = 1:10000
    B_tot = zeros(6,24);
    for j = 1:8
        ddx = 1;
        ddy = 2;
        ddz = 3;
        pos = j*3-2;
        B_tot(1:6,pos:pos+2) = [ddx 0 0;0 ddy 0;0 0 ddz;ddy ddx 0;0 ddz ddy;ddz 0 ddx];
    end
end
toc
tic
for i = 1:10000
    B_tot = zeros(6,24);
    for j = 1:8
        ddx = 1;
        ddy = 2;
        ddz = 3;
        pos = j*3-2;
        B_tot(1,pos) = ddx;
        B_tot(2,pos+1) = ddy;
        B_tot(3,pos+2) = ddz;
        B_tot(4,pos) = ddy;
        B_tot(4,pos+1) = ddx;
        B_tot(5,pos+1) = ddz;
        B_tot(5,pos+2) = ddy;
        B_tot(6,pos) = ddz;
        B_tot(6,pos+2) = ddx;
    end
end
toc
tic
for i = 1:10000
    B_tot = zeros(6,24);
    for j = 1:8
        ddx = 1;
        ddy = 2;
        ddz = 3;
        pos = j*3-2;
        B_tot(sub2ind(size(B_tot),[1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6],pos+[0,1,2,0,1,1,2,0,2]))=[ddx,ddy,ddz,ddy,ddx,ddz,ddy,ddz,ddx];
    end
end
toc
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 0.287602 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.012062 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.510040 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you add examples of `B_tot` and code to reproduce comparable timings? You may also find that `B_tot(sub2ind(size(B_tot),[1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6],pos+[0,1,2,0,1,1,2,0,2]))=[ddx,ddy,ddz,ddy,...]` is a useful shorthand for the 2nd option.

Comment: Note that you are doing fewer assignments in the second case--you're not assigning the zeros. What type is `B_tot`? What types are `ddx` etc?

Comment: Hello Wolfie, I made a small script for comparison in the opener. Your approach was actually the slowest. :(

Comment: Hey Cris, I am aware of the zeros, they are not necessary of course. Still, the difference should not be that huge, shouldn't it? B_tot is a 6xN matrix (N differs), dd* are floats, derivatives of shape functions, to be precise.

Comment: Please use `@Cris` or `@Wolfie` to ping the person you're replying to. That way they get a notification of your reply. (The notification automatically goes to the poster that the comment is attached to, you can add one `@name`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Octave 4.0, I see these timings from running your script:

```
Elapsed time is 2.30614 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.02992 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.84936 seconds.
```

Wolfie's version is the fastest, and the single-element indexing is the slowest!

Octave's JIT (if it has one) is not nearly as good as MATLAB's, hence the relatively slow times.

I think what you see here is that MATLAB's JIT is optimized better somehow for single-element indexing. Note also that

```
B_tot(1:6,pos:pos+2) = [ddx 0 0;0 ddy 0;0 0 ddz;ddy ddx 0;0 ddz ddy;ddz 0 ddx];
```

creates a matrix, copies the values into it, then indexes into `B_tot` and copies the values there. Of course the execution of this could be optimized, but they might not have gotten around to doing so.

Note also that you will see very different timings in different versions of MATLAB. I'm sure that older versions of MATLAB will show timings similar to what I get now with Octave. But it is very possible also that a future version of MATLAB will show a different order for these timings, as they further improve their JIT and optimize more syntax cases.

Answer (score -1):

The underlying implementation of submatrix assignment is made of loops. Loops are always slower than linear programming flow. If you are going down to the assambler layer, loops look a bit like this.

```
Pos  Operation
  1  load variable1, variable2
  2  cmp = compare variable1, variable2
  3  if cmp : goto pos 4, else : goto pos 17
  4  load something
  5  operate on something
...
 16  goto pos 1
 17  load something_else
```

While a linear program does at least have four operations less.

... I know this is not real Assembler, but I do not know the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Although I thought that loops in assembler would not be a big deal - in contrast to Matlab. Do you have an idea to write it in a shorter way in Matlab? I would think Matlab should be able to transform an assignment like that automatically to a faster version.